Restricting read access to MediaWiki pages based on category and group
I have a page with this content, which is a page intended to be accessible only for users in the "sales" group. Even for reading.
This page contains content for sales.

<!-- Tag for AccessControl -->
<accesscontrol>Sales</accesscontrol>

[[Category:Sales]]

The page is in the Sales category. All pages in this category should be accessed only by "sales" group.
But it's not working. No user can read that page now , even the ones in "sales". Help me figure it out please.
ChatGPT suggested a very long configuration including a $wgAccessControlTagPermissions variable, which I haven't even found in the official MediaWiki docs. I guess it's a setting from an old version of mediawiki, I don't know where chatGPT pulled that from.

For all the hype, ChatGPT is not intelligent, and does not access reliable data when answering your queries; it is a very sophisticated string auto-complete. It's quite likely that what you have here is not from any out of date documentation, it's just the language model hallucinating (that's the technical term).

So forget the bot, and go to the MediaWiki manual and from there to the extension's documentation which you can machine translate into English with much lower risk of the tool telling you complete lies.

A good exampple of hallucinating AI. Also, the extension is poorly written and tries to achieve an impossible goal. MediaWiki, by its very architecture, is not meant to restrict read access.

@IMSoP I will try TikiWiki , seems designed for that. Thx

@AlexanderMashin I will try TikiWiki and post the solution if it works. It seems a wiki that addresses exactly my case. Thx

As mentioned in the comments and stated in the docs as Security issues with authorization extensions, MediaWiki doesn't officially support ACL on read permissions.
Things got better in recent releases with MediaWiki core and the new PHP parser, but you should probably not use an extension and you should definitely not configure it with settings invented by a language model.
